# fs Nodejs read data from remote url _ capture stream

Tags: node.js, fs

is it possible to capture data from remote url and store as a file with [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream).problem is how can I listen to the url?

something like this:

```
let data = "capture from url" /// problem 
let file = fs.createWriteStream(`public/capture/file.mp4`, { flags: 'a' });
file.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, for this, you need to install extra packages like got, download, file-type.

```
const download=require("download")
const FileType=require("file-type")
const got = require('got');


async function upload(){
    const url = "your URL"
    const stream = got.stream(url);
    let ext = await FileType.fromStream(stream);
    console.log("ext", ext)
    fs.writeFileSync(location to save file/filename+"."+${ext}, 
    await download(URL));
}

upload()
```